# Wrong item is being highlighted after recomposition in LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LazyVerticalGrid` with `Button`s:

```
@Composable
private fun Grid(
    items: List<ChoiceSelectorItem>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    notifyEvent: (MyUIEvent) -> Unit
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items.forEach { item ->
            item {
                Button(onClick = {
                    notifyEvent(
                        MyUIEvent.OnItemClicked(
                            item = item,
                        )
                    )
                }) {
                    Text(text = item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I click on item I trigger `OnItemClicked` event which updates UI state and sends a new list of `items` to `Grid`. As a result I can see a new set of items on a screen. Sometimes it can be 2 items, sometimes 5.

The problem is - when I click on the Button - it starts "Indication" ripple effect and recomposition triggers and Grid displays a new list of items immediately (even before Indication animation ends). As a result for example when I click on one of the item, Indication animation starts on that item and when list updates - I can receive 3 rows of items instead of 1 and I can see the 2nd part of Indication animation on the item which is not under that place where user clicked.

Is there a way to delay recomposition until Button's indication ripple animation is finished? Maybe there are other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by adding animation between recompositions using `AnimatedContent`:

```
AnimatedContent(
        targetState = page,
        transitionSpec = {
            fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)) with
                fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250))
        }
    ) {
    // LazyVerticalGrid...
}
```